# Am I being unreasonable to force sale of joint property?

Tags: jointly-held-property

I purchased a two bedroom flat with my sister 7 years ago as an investment on the premise that I would live there for a year and then rent out a room to cover my share and my sister would live there. A month after moving in my sister found out she was pregnant and and moved in her partner so it was no longer feasible for me to live there or rent out my room as agreed. I continued to pay my half of the mortgage for close to a year despite moving out and living with my parents as my sister threatened to take the whole flat off me if I stopped paying (I have since found out this wasn’t possible anyway).

After a year we came to an agreement that her partner would pay my half so I could then rent privately however they split up two years later. Since then she has continued to pay the mortgage of £600 per month while I have rented privately- paying £1260 a month.

Due to her situation as a single parent etc I think I have been reasonable up till this point by not forcing her to sell of asking for rent on my half. She still however feels that I should have been contributing to the mortgage and the upkeep of the property.

The situation has recently changed and I have had a baby and my partner’s income has dropped considerably due to covid and so it is no longer possible for us to afford to rent privately when I return to work part time. We would have £40 a week left between us for food and any other living expenses after rent, bills, car, transport costs, childcare and essential expenses for nappies and milk for the baby are taken into consideration.

We have looked into trying to downsize and rent a one bedroom however no landlord will accept us with a baby.

We have also explored the route of trying to get a second mortgage. However as my income in tied up in the first property we can’t get enough to purchase even a one bedroom flat 25 miles outside of the city we live in. If we could purchase our own place our outgoings would be reduced by around £600 a month.

As another option I have asked my parents if they could loan me £60000 to put down as a deposit on a second property (which would enable us to buy somewhere of our own) which would be paid back upon the sale of the first property I share with my sister- but they refused.

As another compromise I had also suggested to my sister that we could sell and buy a larger place together to accommodate all of us but she declined and said she wants her own space.

My sister is saying she can’t sell as she can’t afford to rent privately either however she would gain around £60,000 from the sale of our flat so would have income to support herself. My parents are backing my sister and saying I shouldn’t make her sell and that myself and my partner will have to make do and work second jobs until she has agreed to sell in 4 years as her son can’t move schools and she can’t afford to rent in the same area.

I am being unreasonable in forcing her to sell?

Comment: How much money have you put into this?  Am I understanding correctly that you are no longer contributing to the mortgage?

Comment: She thinks you're being unreasonable, you don't, it's a matter of opinion. An objective analysis of what is equitable would require assigning monetary value to the contributions made by each of you as well as the benefits each of you has received. If you contributed significantly to the purchase via down payment then it feels pretty reasonable to be able to extract that equity in some way.

Comment: We both put in £10k each deposit and paid equally towards the the renovations and for the windows to be replaces two years after purchasing the property

Comment: Who is currently living in the two bedroom flat?

Comment: My sister and her son live there

Comment: "A month after moving in my sister found out she was pregnant and and moved in her partner so it was no longer feasible for me to live there or rent out my room as agreed." — Why was it no longer feasible?

Comment: What changed that made you decide to move out?  If your sister had one bedroom then her partner and the baby could share it and you keep your own room as agreed in the first place.  It almost sounds like you were being nice and moved of your own accord.  I would emphasize that this is what happens when people get into joint ventures like this without a written agreement setting out rules, division of expenses, sale conditions, and division of proceeds.  Just because she's your sister doesn't change the legal obligation to protect your own interests.  It sounds like quite a mess for you.